# v4l2loopback label in webrtc

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, chromium, v4l2loopback

In the v4l2loopback program, the card_label parameter places a label on each created camera, and this is identified in Chrome / Chromium, as shown.

[image]

But the output of the javascript command to list devices, does not show this information, I expected it to be in ***label***, as picture below:

[image]

Is there another way to identify the correct device?

Curiously in Electron (where I actually intend to use this code), it works as expected, but should not the Renderer behave as it does in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, it is because of the default behavior of Electron, where anything that is not expressly prohibited, is allowed, in the browser the label is only displayed after accepting which device will be used to capture the media.
And the call 'enumerateDevices ()' does not trigger the routine to select devices